# opensaml java encrypted assertion - Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using EncryptedKeyResolver

Tags: java, spring, saml, okta, opensaml

I've setup a developer account on okta and I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted assertion from the test app I set up in there.  So my local java Spring app has a controller that's receiving the HTTP POST of the SAML assertion - I've verified this with it not being encrypted.  Now with encryption turned on, I'm attempting to decrypt it with this method:

```
private Assertion decrypt(EncryptedAssertion encryptedAssertion) {//throws DecryptionException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException {
    StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver keyInfoCredentialResolver = new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(spConfig.getCredential());
    Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter(null, keyInfoCredentialResolver, new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());
    decrypter.setRootInNewDocument(true);
    try {
        return decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("oops", e.getCause());
        return null;
    }
}
```

with this SP config code:

```
private static final String KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "mypassw";
private static final String KEY_STORE_ENTRY_PASSWORD = "mypassw";
private static final String KEY_STORE_PATH = "/keystore.p12";
private static final String KEY_ENTRY_ID = "http://www.okta.com/exkz............42p6";

private static Credential credential = null;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, ResolverException {
    log.debug("doing init");
    KeyStore keystore = readKeystoreFromFile(KEY_STORE_PATH, KEY_STORE_PASSWORD);
    Map<String, String> passwordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwordMap.put(KEY_ENTRY_ID, KEY_STORE_ENTRY_PASSWORD);
    KeyStoreCredentialResolver resolver = new KeyStoreCredentialResolver(keystore, passwordMap);

    EntityIdCriterion criteria = new EntityIdCriterion(KEY_ENTRY_ID);
    CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet(criteria);

    credential = resolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
}

private static KeyStore readKeystoreFromFile(String pathToKeyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    InputStream inputStream = SpConfig.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToKeyStore);
    keystore.load(inputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    inputStream.close();
    return keystore;
}

public Credential getCredential() {
    return credential;
}
```

I've tried a few things to purposely break the code -- bad keystore pw, missing keystore, incorrectly typed keyentry alias, and I do get errors that point to that.  But when it looks like it's set up correctly, all I get is this:

```
2018-04-18 08:40:07.502 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.core.xml.util.XMLObjectSupport       : Parsing InputStream into DOM document
2018-04-18 08:40:07.503 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.core.xml.util.XMLObjectSupport       : Unmarshalling DOM parsed from InputStream
2018-04-18 08:40:07.574 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.x.s.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller       : Starting to unmarshall Apache XML-Security-based SignatureImpl element
2018-04-18 08:40:07.575 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.x.s.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller       : Constructing Apache XMLSignature object
2018-04-18 08:40:07.578 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy      : setElement("ds:Signature", "")
2018-04-18 08:40:07.580 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy      : setElement("ds:SignedInfo", "")
2018-04-18 08:40:07.580 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy      : setElement("ds:SignatureMethod", "")
2018-04-18 08:40:07.580 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.x.s.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm    : Create URI "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" class "class org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.implementations.SignatureBaseRSA$SignatureRSASHA256"
2018-04-18 08:40:07.581 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.xml.security.algorithms.JCEMapper    : Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256
2018-04-18 08:40:07.581 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.x.s.a.i.SignatureBaseRSA             : Created SignatureRSA using SHA256withRSA
2018-04-18 08:40:07.585 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.xml.security.utils.ElementProxy      : setElement("ds:KeyInfo", "")
2018-04-18 08:40:07.585 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.x.s.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller       : Adding canonicalization and signing algorithms, and HMAC output length to Signature
2018-04-18 08:40:07.585 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.x.s.impl.SignatureUnmarshaller       : Adding KeyInfo to Signature
2018-04-18 08:40:07.597 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.core.xml.util.XMLObjectSupport       : InputStream succesfully unmarshalled
2018-04-18 08:40:07.618 DEBUG 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter  : Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using EncryptedKeyResolver
2018-04-18 08:40:07.618 ERROR 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter  : Failed to decrypt EncryptedData using either EncryptedData KeyInfoCredentialResolver or EncryptedKeyResolver + EncryptedKey KeyInfoCredentialResolver
2018-04-18 08:40:07.619 ERROR 20655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.o.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter      : SAML Decrypter encountered an error decrypting element content

org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.DecryptionException: Failed to decrypt EncryptedData
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:550) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-3.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:452) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-3.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:412) ~[opensaml-xmlsec-api-3.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:176) [opensaml-saml-api-3.3.0.jar:na]
        at org.opensaml.saml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:104) [opensaml-saml-api-3.3.0.jar:na]
```

I've been over so much github, source examples and such --- I think I've got the concise bit of code that should do this.  but obviously something is missing.  Unlike samples where Spring security is involved, I don't have a place for IDP or SP metadata.  Should it be there somewhere?

I've also seen various posts about illegal key size - I don't have that exception, but in case some try-catches or logging was changed or something, I installed the unlimited strength JCE jars.

Comment: What information are you hoping to get out of the assertion? Maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: Ultimately, I need to get to the assertion attributes inside the attribute statement.  But I'll also need to validate the assertion over all.

Comment: Make sure that you are using correct private key.

Comment: Of course -- I've tried this two ways -- an openssl key generation and creating a pkcs12 keystore out of that.  and a jks keystore from a keytool key generation (with RSA key alg stuff).  I've kept the two certs separate and have compared the logged encrypted SAML response string where my cert is included in the payload where it was used to encrypt the one-time key for the real SAML assertion content.  I was at one time worried because of some wonkiness with the HTML form at okta that my cert wasn't being picked up, but it's definitely there and in the posted content.

Comment: meh - for what it's worth, I purposely used the wrong keystore and got the same error.  I dunno anymore.

Answer (score 5):

got it working with by using a chaining resolver as per this sample -

```
final List<EncryptedKeyResolver> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());
list.add(new EncryptedElementTypeEncryptedKeyResolver());
list.add(new SimpleRetrievalMethodEncryptedKeyResolver());
LOGGER.debug("Built a list of encrypted key resolvers: [{}]", list);
final ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver encryptedKeyResolver = new ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver(list);
```

from http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.opensaml.xmlsec.encryption.support.ChainingEncryptedKeyResolver

Comment: May I ask how did you found out the StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver isn't working? As it is the example in the official paid OpenSAML <<Guide to ...>> book.

Comment: I confirm this solution works for Okta's encryption where the OpenSAML V3 example doesn't.

Comment: I can also confirm that Encryption with OKTA SAML not working but at the same OneLogin is working fine.